# How i should integrate twitter in my app?

Tags: android, twitter

I want to integrate twitter in my android app.

I have used twitter4j,jtwitter but i think i might went wrong somewhere.

If anyone is having the sample demo created by them then plz upload it.

thnx 4 any help....

Comment: try this link dude.. http://thetechnib.blogspot.com/2011/01/android-sign-in-with-twitter.html

Comment: What kind of integration? Just adding a "Share" functionality is the easiest and requires not additional libraries.

Comment: is there twitter sdk for android present.if any one has done in his app then plz give sample how should i use in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to add a share functionality to your app.

```
 final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "something to share");
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```

This will create a chooser so the user can select any Activity that can handle the Intent.ACTION_SEND intent. This includes the sms app, gmail, facebook, twitter, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to implement it will be to use intent. http://labs.emich.be/2010/01/23/how-to-send-to-twitter-or-facebook-from-your-android-application/ which will work if you have installed the twitter client on you phone but you wont bother with login, auth etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily integrate Twitter in your android application .

1. I have use this [sample](https://github.com/VishnuGShephertz/Twiitter-Integration-on-Android) for Twitter integration in android application.
2. This sample contains all the steps required to integrate Twitter in android application